# Deleting an XML Node within a parent

Tags: php, xml

I have an XML file with a root, a parent node and some inner nodes. If I use DOM->load(myxmlfile.xml) is it possible to traverse through the nodes and remove the imageurlnode?

I have tried this example:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->load('myxmlfile.xml');

$book = $doc->documentElement;

// we retrieve the chapter and remove it from the book
$node = $book->getElementsByTagName('imageurl')->item(0);
$oldnode = $book->removeChild($chapter);

echo $doc->saveXML();
```

But this only removes items from underneath root. My XML has the following structure:

```
<root>
    <property>
        <imageurl></imageurl>
    </property
</root>
```

So when it comes to removing the imgurl node (as it's inside a parent inside the root) how would I remove it?

Comment: `getElementsByTagName('chapter')` your example doucment has notelement chapter. Can you please make the example code and the example document match?

Comment: PHP is what i am using

Comment: Now your example doesn't work at all - there are at least two errors: `</property` is missing an `>` and `Undefined variable: chapter ... on line 9`. Sorry for being a bit picky but ....

Answer (score 1):

If you have the node, say `$chapter`, just use its parent to delete it

```
$chapter->parentNode->removeChild($chapter);
```